# AM trying to add AutoSlider Timer Android

Tags: android, timer, slider, tablayout

and am getting this Error.

MainActivity.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
sliderTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AutoSlider(), 4000, 6000);
^
symbol:   class AutoSlider
location: class MainActivity

**CODE**

```
        sliderTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AutoSlider(), 4000, 6000);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(bannerMoviesViewPager, true)

        class AutoSlider extends TimerTask{


            @Override
            public void run() {

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(() ->{
                    if (bannerMoviesViewPager.setCurrentItem()< bannerMoviesList.size() - 1){

                        bannerMoviesViewPager.setCurrentItem(bannerMoviesViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);

                    }
                    else{
                        bannerMoviesViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

                    }

                });
```